# calling mysql procedure using codeigniter [Error: result consisted more than one row]

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table **status** and **status_stage** . After insert in **status** table, I want to add it to the **status_stage** table. I have this procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addStatus`(status VARCHAR(45), stage int (8))
BEGIN

    DECLARE status_id INT DEFAULT NULL; 

    INSERT INTO status (status)
    VALUES (status);

    SELECT id INTO status_id FROM status WHERE status = status;

    INSERT INTO stage_status (stage,status)
    VALUES (stage,id);
END
```

And I call that function with this:

```
$result= $this->db->query("call addStatus('$status', $stage)"); 
return ($result->num_rows()>0);
```

When I tried it it gives me this Error:

> Result consisted of more than one row

Comment: What does `status` table contain after executing the procedure?

Comment: @Raptor, It inserts the data into the `status ` table. But returns the error. I guess , the error is in the `SELECT id INTO status_id FROM status WHERE status = status;`. But this statement will only result to one row. I can't figure out where's exactly the error is..

Comment: Find it..Atlast! Variable name should be different from the field name of the database table..

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT ... INTO` statement got more than one result because of your `WHERE` clause with `status = status`, this equals forever

you need to change the param name to distinguish it from the table column name (eg. status_param)